# getting error while inserting data by file in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data via text file in Mysql Database and getting This error

```
1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

 ADOConnection._Execute(LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/in2fonenew/inv/test.txt'
 INTO TABLE  tbl_transaction FIELDS TERMINATED BY '||' enclosed by '`..., false)
```

And the Query is Mentioned Below for this Purpose

```
$sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$docroot."/inv/".$dbfile."' INTO TABLE 
tbl_transaction FIELDS TERMINATED BY '||' enclosed by '`' LINES TERMINATED
 BY '|||||' (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6)";
```

What i have done Wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/weecology/retriever/issues/31)

> "If LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message: 
>    ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` must be explicitly enabled.

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL 5.5 manual page:

> LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been
>   configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with
>   --local-infile=0, LOCAL does not work. See Section 6.1.6, “Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL”.

You should set the option:

```
local-infile=1
```

into your **[mysql]** entry of my.cnf file or call mysql client with the **--local-infile** option:

```
mysql --local-infile -uroot -pyourpwd yourdbname
```

You have to be sure that the same parameter is defined into your **[mysqld]** section too to enable the "local infile" feature server side.

It's a security restriction.